# Array element comparison in x86-64 Assembly (AT&T syntax)

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64, att

I'm trying to write a simple procedure in x86-64 assembly that simply returns the length of an array of ints.  The last element in the array is a 0, which should not be counted.  The array is passed in as an int * from C code.

My assembly code is as follows:

```
f1:
    movq $0, %rax   # zero out %rax
    jmp   test      # jump to test
body:
    incq  %rax      # increment %rax, which is counter and array index

test:
    cmpq   $0, (%rdi,%rax,4)  # compare (rdi + (rax * 4)) to 0
    jne    body   # jump if zero flag is not set
ret
```

When this runs, I get a result that is not correct, but not wildly incorrect either, so instead of 11 (size of array passed minus ending 0) I get 38. What I think is happening is that my compare statement is incorrect. My thinking was that since cmpq performs (dest - src) without altering the registers, if the array index is 0, 0-0 would yield a zero so the zero flag would be set, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

I can arbitrarily load any element of the array into %rax, which returns the correct value:

```
movq   (%rdi,%rax,4), %rax   # %rax initially 0, so first element loaded into %rax
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well done keeping your code very short, just the part that's not doing what you think it should.  And for explaining what you thought was supposed to happen, so it was easy to explain just that specific thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is 32 bits (4 bytes) in both x86-64 ABIs (SystemV and Windows).  (See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for details).

`cmpq   $0, (%rdi,%rax,4)` correctly scales the index by 4, **but incorrectly uses 64bit operand-size.  (`q` stands for quad-word**.  In Intel's x86 terminology, a "word" is 16 bits.)

**`cmpq` was comparing two consecutive elements**.  The equivalent C would be `while( 0 != *(int64_t*)&(array[i]) ){ ++i; }`

---

Outside of x86, a word is usually the register size of the machine or something like that, so it matches the size of `long`.  e.g. a word is 32bits on 32bit MIPS.

It's just terminology, and it's handy to have convenient names like word (AT&T syntax `w` suffix), dword (`l` suffix), qword (`q` suffix).

In `gdb`, in some places "word" is 32bits even when debugging x86 (e.g. the `x` command to dump memory has `b` (byte), `h` (half word: 16b), `w` (word), and `g` (giant: 8B) size format specifiers.

Comment: Thank you very much, and for the extra trivia as well.  I changed the instruction to 'cmpl' and the correct values are being returned, but I'm not sure I understand why.  Is the operand-size affecting the scaling value for the offset?

Comment: @joezuu: No, your addressing was always correct.  Updated the answer with what `cmpq` was actually doing.